# Fetching and Parsing Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've overridden the `parse` function of a collection I'm fetching as so:

```
parse: function(response) {
    this.total = response.total;
    return response.items;
}
```

Further, I've bound the collection to the render function of the view that uses it. 
`this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);`

The collection itself is fetched in the collection's initialize function:
`this.collection.fetch({ data: params });`

The collection is then accessed in subviews:

```
render: function() {
  var catalog, pages;
  catalog = new App.Views.Catalog({collection: this.collection});
  pages = new App.Views.Pages({collection: this.collection});

  return this;
}
```

**NOTE:**

The only way I could get it work was by changing the binding to: `this.collection.bind('add', this.render);`, which ends up calling `render` four times.

Comment: My current answer may not fix the problem.  Can you post more code where you fetch the objects, and where you attempt to view the value of `this.total`?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bind `this` to the render function.  Change:

```
this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
```

To:

```
this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have: `_.bindAll(this, 'render')` before `this.collection.bind('reset', this.render)`

Comment: OK cool.  Do you mind posting more code, especially where fetch is called and where you can see the problem with total not being set?